# Android - ScaleAnimation from center doesn't work as intended for some views

Tags: android, android-layout, android-animation

I have an activity, and on onCreate I run this piece of code:

```
    AnimationSet animation = new AnimationSet(true);
    animation.addAnimation(new AlphaAnimation(0f, 1f));
    animation.addAnimation(new ScaleAnimation(0f, 1f, 0f, 1f, Animation.RELATIVE_TO_SELF, 0.5f, Animation.RELATIVE_TO_SELF, 0.5f));
    animation.setDuration(4000); // should be 300
    animation.setFillAfter(true);

    View i1 = findViewById(R.id.load_mainimg);
    View i2 = findViewById(R.id.load_text1);
    View i3 = findViewById(R.id.load_text2);
    View i4 = findViewById(R.id.load_imgbtn_about);
    View i5 = findViewById(R.id.load_imgbtn_settings);
    View i6 = findViewById(R.id.load_btn1);
    View i7 = findViewById(R.id.load_btn2);
    i1.startAnimation(animation);
...
    i7.startAnimation(animation);
```

However, the TextViews (i2, i3) and the ImageButtons (i4, i5) doesn't scale from the center. (i1 is an ImageView, i6 and i7 are LinearLayouts.) What am I doing wrong?

Comment: hmm... maybe try temporarily setting a background color on those views to see if the center of the view is where you expect it to be.

Comment: Show your xml code